# Error converting Retrofit response to local model

Tags: java, android, rest, retrofit, retrofit2

I am using Retrofit to communicate with a REST based service and in my Android App I have a local domain model. To isolate my App from any changes and dependencies on the REST service I want to convert the objects returned from the REST service to my local domain model.

Currently I am doing this by passing the object returned by the response.body() to the constructor of the corresponding class in my model. This works great for all basic properties like ints, Strings etc. except for more complex objects like List<>. Here is my class:

```
public abstract class MetadataAsset<T> implements Comparable<T> {

    protected Long id;
    protected String title;
    protected String description;
    protected List<String> genres;
    protected List<CastMember> cast;

    public MetadataAsset(no.external.entities.MetadataAsset metadataAsset) {
        this.id = metadataAsset.id;
        this.title = metadataAsset.title;
        this.description = metadataAsset.description;
        this.genres = metadataAsset.genres;

        this.cast = new ArrayList<>();
        if(metadataAsset.cast != null) {
            for (no.external.entities.CastMember castMember : metadataAsset.cast) {
                this.cast.add(new CastMember(castMember));
            }
        }

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
         return title;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
         return description;
    }

    public List<String> getGenres() {
         return genres;
    }

    public List<CastMember> getCast() {
         return cast;
    }
}
```

The object passed to the constructor is the object returned by the response.body() by Retrofit. Before passing this object to the MetadataAsset constructor I check that the size of the cast list is not null and the number of elements in the list is > 0 and I get the correct number of elements, but when I do the same test inside the constructor, the list is now null.

Looking at the genres list, the result is different. The list has the same number of elements both before passing the object to the constructor and inside the constructor.

Is there some sort of GC going on here that I do not understand? Why would the list be NULL inside the constructor when it is not outside?

And how should this be structured?

Comment: Well, you may try create an empty constructor, I guess retrofit always request a empty constructor. But could you paste the error? It will be easier to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just use `Serializable` and let the converter you chose to work with Retrofit do the work?

For instance, in your code, you can make your custom objects `implement Serializable` and then also annotate fields that you want mapped from the JSON with `@SerializedName` annotation on them, passing the json attribute name as a parameter to the annotation, like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZH6S.png).

Hope this might help.